# Android SQLCipher BLOB Performance

Tags: android, sql, blob, sqlcipher

I want to **store blobs in a sql database thats encrypted by sql cipher**.

My blobs are images with an **average size of 40kb**.

Has anyone of you experience with sql cipher and blobs?

**I would like to know if i can expect an acceptable performance.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I store images of any size (dependent on camera) the database is sql cipher images can be 3-4 MB in size. at a time I can store 10 images which would max take 4 seconds (this time also includes other heavy stuff) but the performance is quiet reasonable 40KB should not be any trouble at all. Go for it No worries

Comment: For optimal performance, you should store your blob data in a separate table. This will allow sqlcipher to search trough metadata tables without decrypting all of the blob content.